# Colour User Defined selected cells and add text to last cell in selection in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to colour a users defined selection in Excel and then add a text entry to the last cell of the selection.

So far I have the selection but sorted but struggling on the text entry.

```
Dim Cell As Object
Sheets("Jobs").Activate
For Each Cell In Selection
Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
Next Cell
```

Comment: No time to answer sorry but one way is you could add a counter in your loop and check it against the number of selected cells - something like `CellCount = CellCount+1` and `If CellCount = Selection.Count Then Cell.Text = "Your Text Here"` - not tested but an idea for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set a range object on every loop which will end up being the last one by the time it's done ...

```
Dim Cell As Range, objLastCell As Range

Sheets("Jobs").Activate

For Each Cell In Selection
    Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
    Set objLastCell = Cell
Next Cell

objLastCell.Value = InputBox("Enter some text and I'll throw it in cell " & objLastCell.Address & " ...", "Enter Text")
```

... something like that anyway.

Also, this assumes the last cell is the last selected, not the last (i.e. the bottom right) cell in the selection.